# Xcode UIScrollView zoom same as MKMapView zoom (no effect on subview)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, mkmapview, zooming

I want to add zoom effect on my `UIScrollView` . That i have achieved it with `UIScrollView` delegate methods.

`(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`.

Now i want to add the effect that `MKMapView` is having in it, that if we zoom-in or zoom-out the `MKMapView` place marker of the map remains at same place and same size. How can can we achieve the same effect with `UIScrollView` zoom effect.

My initial guess is to do something with `CGAffineTransform`. But the question is when and how?

Thanks,
Jay Stepin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to zoom your scroll view in and out while all visual objects on it remain "anchored" to their locations. I'd suggest you use `UIScrollView`'s `zoomScale` property which tells you the multiplier you should apply to your scroll view's content positions.

Say, initially you have some object (`UIImage`, for example) with it's `center` at `x = 100.0`, `y = 100.0` and `zoomScale = 1.0`. Define a couple of constants/variables to store those coordinates somewhere (let's call them `initialX` and `initialY`, for example). Then you track `zoomScale` value in `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol's `- scrollViewDidZoom:` method and simply multiply the initial (not current!) coordinates with `zoomScale`'s value.

E.g. (adjust for your code):

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat currentScale = scrollView.zoomScale;

    // Adjust object's position.
    CGPoint currentCenter = yourObject.center;

    currentCenter.x = initialX * currentScale;
    currentCenter.y = initialY * currentScale;

    yourObject.center = currentCenter;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I mark your answer and it is the solution too. But in my case i handle it by re adjusting the frame rather just moving the center.